# Drupal images/links at the wrong URL(sometimes)

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I have a Drupal website installed on cPanel.
the site is at http://example.com

Everything is working good, however at times, sometimes the images/links will be changed to a different URL then the main url, it will be at https://randomurl.com

The images/links still work fine under the new url, however I would prefer it not go to the new url, as i am selling that url shortly.

i have went into settings.php and added $base_url to the main url, but nothing have changed.

Comment: Hi, alex. Where are these links? Are they in the body text or somewhere else?

Comment: They are within the source. so the images for example would be from a different url at time.

Comment: it all depends on how images are rendered in the preprocess/process or the template files.